# MySQL: Syntax error while creating a table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wanted to create a new table, but I have a syntax error somewhere.
However I do not see where, no matter how often I look over it.

Can anybody spot my error?

```
Dim cmdCreate As New MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE inout (inout_seacher TEXT,inout_guid TEXT,inout_blob LONGBLOB,inout_inouttype INTEGER,inout_automaticallyparsed TINYINT(1)," & _
                                  "inout_price DOUBLE,inout_companyguid TEXT,inout_datetime TEXT,inout_title TEXT,inout_catid INTEGER,inout_vat INTEGER,inout_banktype INTEGER," & _
                                  "inout_banktransferprice DOUBLE,inout_expenseinvoiceexistsinguid TEXT,inout_orderguid TEXT,inout_inoutsubtype INTEGER,inout_outinvoicetype INTEGER)", g_CnWebDB)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Strawberry LOL@InOut :-))) Thank you for the info. And thank you for the DECIMAL as well! Can you make your comment the reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad luck. Believe it or not 'inout' is a reserved word in MySQL. Either wrap it in backticks (`) or (better) call it something else. Also, are you sure you want DOUBLE and not DECIMAL?

Answer (score 0):

"inout" is reserved word. Try other name for the table.
You can also quote the table's name using (`), so (`inout`) becomes acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry already said, is a reserved word used for procedures; directly from MySQL.com:

> As of MySQL 5.0.30, stored procedures that take no arguments can be
>   invoked without parentheses. That is, CALL p() and CALL p are
>   equivalent.
>
> CALL can pass back values to its caller using parameters that are
>   declared as OUT or **INOUT** parameters. When the procedure returns, a
>   client program can also obtain the number of rows affected for the
>   final statement executed within the routine: At the SQL level, call
>   the ROW_COUNT() function; from the C API, call the
>   mysql_affected_rows() function.